# Android - How to refresh my listview after adding item to the database through a dialogfragment

Tags: android, sql, database

I have a `DialogFragment` from where i am adding the item to the database table.

And i have another `Fragment`, which has a `ListView` where i am displaying all items from the database. 
I could add the item to the database, but it doesn't immediately appear on the `ListView`, which is fetching the items from database.

Comment: Can you show us your `MyListAdapter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method `yourListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` , see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

**EDIT :**

you add the item to database from fragment A , so you should create a global variable for your listAdapter in the fragment B ( the one which contains the `listView`) , and get your fragment in your Fragment A by tag , and then you should call :

```
//when you add the fragmentB to your Activity , make sure you set a Tag for it
FragmentB f = (FragmentB) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_B);

f.getMyListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT 2 :**

in your `CustomListAdapter` , add a method to refresh your List of objects ( `my` ) :

```
public void setMyList(List myListOfObjects) {
    this.my = myListOfObjects;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then , when you add the new Object to your database, retreive all data from the database, and then call :

```
f.getMyListAdapter().setMyList(newListOfObjects);//newListOFObjects contains the new data
```

Comment: I've tried using this , but it gives an error that notifydatasetchanged is undefined . I tried to use it in dialogfragment class after onclick

Comment: it is undefined because you called it on an instance which is not your listAdpater ? which sdk version you use ???

Comment: i updated the code with satriano's , which is similar to yours , but still my list is not refreshing . Am i using notifydatasetchanged() at the right place ?

Comment: the notifyDataSetChanged() should be called after the add :) , so refresh your List which you call it " my" , and then call the method notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: i did that , but nothing happening . how to refresh the list before calling noifydatasetchanged ()

Comment: it's not working properly , it's adding the item , but then my last item is not being displayed after i am adding any item

Comment: make sure that you update your datasource ArrayList , try to debbug it

Comment: ListAdapter::notifyDataSetChanged() - no such method.

Comment: @TomeeNS : The adapter the you have for your ListView contains the method notifyDataSetChanged() method. check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged(). 

PS : the getMyListAdapter() method is a getter that you may add to your fragment to facilitate accessing it and refreshing your list outside of your fragment ( example : your activity that hold this fragment) .

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable for your `MyListAdapter`

```
MyListAdapter adapter;
...

adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), my);
```

Create a getter in the fragment where it exists:

```
public MyListAdapter getAdapter() {

    return adapter;
}
```

When you create a new entry in the database, call this:

```
//Make sure you make a tag when you add your fragment
MyFrag f = (MyFrag) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(YOURTAGHERE);

f.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should work, but you will need to do some debugging/logic of your own to get it done.

**EDIT**:  Here's the method:

```
public void updateList() {

List<MyItem> l = db.getAllMyItem();

    for(MyItem cn :l )
    {
        cn = l.get(0);
        l.remove(0);
        my.add(new MyList(cn.getName(),0));
    }

}
```

Comment: i updated the code with this , but still i got no errors  , but it isn't refreshing my list immedaitely , nothing is happening .

Comment: After looking at your code again, you need to update your "my" `List` with the database.  Create a public method that does this and call it along with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Create an global object from your custom adapter class.

```
MyListAdapter mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), my);
```

And set your listView's adapter:

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Just refresh your array, named "my", in your adapter.
And then call:

```
 mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it'll do the trick...

Comment: refresh array in adapter , i don't understand that part ? could you explain a little bit more .

Comment: Your listView shows only items in your array that you send it to your arrayAdapter, which is "my" in your situation... You just need to remove items in "my" array and add new ones, or just add one item... Whatever you want. And then call notifyDataSetChanged, so your arrayAdapter will know that list items have changed...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the adapter again to the listView this will raise the update

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```